# Shiny with HTML template fails to get a value from a dynamic SELECT / OPTIONS

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I would like to create a Shiny app based on a htmltemplate. When I create a static SELECT/OPTION html, a selected value from an OPTION is available in the server script and I can e.g. display it back in the UI, but when I generate SELECT/OPTION html with R code, I can not render the selected value back in the UI.

Is there a way generate a dynamic SELECT/OPTION list and use the selected value in the R code?

html template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.0.5];htmlwidgets[1.0];plotly-binding[4.7.1];bootstrap[3.3.7]</script>
  <script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
  <script src="htmlwidgets-1.0/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
  <script src="plotly-binding-4.7.1/plotly.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- FIRST SELECT -->
  <select name="car1">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <!-- SELECTED VALUE WILL BE DISPLAYED HERE - WORKS FINE -->
  <div class="shiny-html-output" id="w1"></div>

  <!-- SECOND SELECT -->
  <select class="shiny-html-output" name="car2" id="i"></select>

  <!-- SELECTED VALUE WILL BE DISPLAYED HERE - DOES NOT WORK -->
  <div class="shiny-html-output" id="w2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

R code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

shinyApp(

  ui <- htmlTemplate("template.html"),  

  server <- function(input, output) {

    # INSERT SELECTED VALUE BELOW FIRST SELECT
    output$w1 <- renderText(input$car1)

    # GENERATE OPTIONS
    html <- ""
    for(r in 1:nrow(mtcars)){
      html <- paste(html, "<option value='",mtcars[r, "mpg"],"'>",mtcars[r,"mpg"],"</option>", sep="")
    }

    # INJECT INTO TEMPLATE
    output$i <- renderText(html)

    # INSERT SELECTED VALUE BELOW SECOND SELECT (DOES NOT WORK)
    output$w2 <- renderText(input$car2)

  }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that one html tag cannot be input and output for Shiny. When the app is launched Shiny server adds both css classes:

- shiny-bound-output
- shiny-bound-input

which seems to create some conflict.

A solution is to use an addional containter so Shiny input and output are not in the same html tags.